# how to EnsureVisible a newly added item on qlistwidget in python?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget

when i added an item in a qlistwiget and reaches the bottom. A scroll bar appears, how can i ensurevisible an item that was newly added from the qlistwidget? Or how can i get the focus to the last index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QListWidget` inherits from [`QAbstractItemView`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html), which has the methods you are looking for:

- You can use [`QAbstractItemView.scrollTo(ModelIndex index)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#scrollTo), using the index of your newly added item.
- Alternatively, since your item is always appended to the end of the list, just call [`QAbstractItemView.scrollToBottom()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#scrollToBottom).

Answer (score 2):

After creating the new `QListWidgetItem`, pass it to [QListWidget.scrollToItem](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qlistwidget.html#scrollToItem) to ensure that it becomes visible.

Note that `scrollToItem` also has a [scroll hint](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#ScrollHint-enum) parameter that allows fine-tuning of how the item is re-positioned in the list widget.